# What is SystemD's default value for LimitNOFILE (on CentOS7)

Tags: centos, systemd, limits

It seems like a very easy question but I couldn't find, what the default for services in SystemD for LimitNOFILE is.

Is there a file with global defaults?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

systemd imposes no such limit by default. however pam_limits generally does, configuration file is /etc/security/limits.conf

Comment: Thanks! So one could say that SystemD just overrides the ordinary Linux limits?

Comment: Systemd is able to raise or decrease the system defaults, please see http://serverfault.com/questions/356962/where-are-the-default-ulimit-values-set-linux-centos top comment for a longer more detailed explanation

Comment: For us, systemd did impose this limit (ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04). We had all of our servers crash and changing `LimitNOFILE` to a high value did fix the problem. Limits in `/etc/security/limits.conf` were set high enough and increasing it alone did not fix the problem.

Maybe it has been changed since 2015.

Comment: it appears `/etc/systemd/system.conf` now does apply a limit (see the other answer)

Answer (score 6):

```
#/etc/security/limits.conf
#This file sets the resource limits for the users logged in via PAM.
#It does not affect resource limits of the system services.
#if your program startup via systemctl
#config /etc/systemd/system.conf
DefaultLimitNOFILE=
```

Answer (score 3):

The default config is in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`, and the default value is `DefaultLimitNOFILE=1024:524288`.